# DataGridView C# binding multiple Lists

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, datasource

Basically I have a List within a List that i want to bind to a dataGridView. It's like this

```
public class Town {
    public List<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
}

public class Shop {
    public List<Car> Cars {get; set; }
}
```

and the class Cars with some properties and overriding the ToString method.

Now, I want to display on the grid rows the Shops with the Cars's properties in the columns.

I also serialize and deserialize the Town object into an XML. I found a way to modify the DataSource object so it can store user's input, but I cannot display the data from a loaded XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not apparent what the problem is. From what you've said, it should be fairly straightforward. Deserialize the Town object back into an object graph and you'd be able to do something like this:

```
var shop = town.Shops[0];
grid.DataSource = shop.Cars;
```

and that should be enough, provided your grid is correctly configured at design-time.

The Car type must expose its data as public properties for this to work, not as fields.